# Utility to include css and js

Tags: html, linux, build

I have a repository of some web files I'm building. There are a few stylesheets that I maintain separately so they're included with `<link>` tags. To deploy the HTML I need to replace the `<link>` tags with `<style>` tags containing the content of the file. Sort of like using `#include <style.css>`

**Is there a good Linux utility that I can use in a `Makefile`?**  Do any of the HTML preprocessors do this sort of thing?  (This is different from CSS inlining.)

To be more specific:

- I'm writing a [custom brew sheet](https://github.com/brundage/beersmith-things) for BeerSmith - which is just an HTML page.
- I'm using a couple of stylesheets for a grid layout, print layout, cleanup some unwanted auto-generated HTML, etc.
- I would rather maintain each sheet separately instead of stuffing it all into one page.
- BeerSmith does not include the separate CSS when exporting recipes, so I need to build in in to the final brew sheet.
- I have a `deploy` script to copy the sheets into my .beersmith3 directory which I'd like to use to assemble the sheet.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="beersmith-cleanup.css" />
  etc ....
```

Comment: can you put some sample or actual html page ? this can be done with sed  find and replace with help of regex. what kind of tool are you looking for ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: Updated with some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have known there was a perl utility.... The [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/index.html) solves this problem handily.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)</title>
  <style>
    [% INCLUDE base.css %]
    [% INCLUDE grid.css %]
    [% INCLUDE beersmith_cleanup.css %]
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="beersmith_cleanup.css" />
</head>
```

Command line

```
0 fatty:0.0 .beersmith3/Reports % tpage test.html > llama.html
```

Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)</title>
  <style>
    @media screen {
  html {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very specific to your case

```
sed -e 's/<link\(.*\)>/<style\1>/' -e 's/<\/link\(.*\)>/<\/style\1>/' <filename>
```

here is sample output
Note I have added two line to handle `<link>` and `</link>` cases

```
cat x 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="beersmith-cleanup.css" />
  <link>
  </link>
```

output is

```
sed -e 's/<link\(.*\)>/<style\1>/' -e 's/<\/link\(.*\)>/<\/style\1>/' x
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dean's Brewsheet (version 2019-12-08)</title>
  <style rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
  <style rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" />
  <style rel="stylesheet" href="beersmith-cleanup.css" />
  <style>
  </style>
```

Comment: This does not actually replace the style tag with the file, simply changes the word `style` to `link`.

Comment: can you come up with a scenario where this will fail to replace the tag ?

Comment: This solution shouldn't be down voted. It solves the problem, be it elegant or not. Sed also works perfectly within a makefile

Comment: It does not solve the problem. I need to replace the <link> tags with <style> tags containing the **content** of the file, not just changing link to style.